# What happens when I range over an uninitialized pointer to array in golang

Tags: go, pointers

I have this code

```
var j *[33]byte

for i := range j {
    fmt.Println(j[i])
}
```

Now when I run this code I get `nil pointer dereference error` when I try access values in `j`. I'm not sure why I was even able to enter the loop in the first place considering my pointer is uninitialized.

I know an uninitialized array has all its values set to their zero value. That is

```
var a [5]int
```

Will have a default value of `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

But I don't understand what golang does when you don't initialize a pointer to an array. Why is `range` able to range over it even though its nil?

Comment: `j` is nil and `a` isn't. This has literally _nothing_ to do with arrays and iteration via range.

Comment: j is nil and the question is why I can range over it. I cannot range over a nil map or slice.

Comment: No, you cannot range over j as you get a nil pointer dereference. But you can range over a nil slice.

Comment: You can actually range over a nil pointer array. You only get a nil pointer dereference only when you try to access elements in the array.

Comment: No you cannot. Really.

Comment: Lol that's funny considering I put up code above that shows you can. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: No, your code doesn't iterate over a nil pointer to an array/slice. A non nil pointer to an array of whatever is a different thing.

Answer (score 3):

From the Go spec [Range Clause](https://go.dev/ref/spec#RangeClause):

> ... For an array, pointer to array, or slice value a, the index
> iteration values are produced in increasing order...

so as a convenience the Go language is dereferencing the pointer with the intent to iterating over its elements. The fact that the pointer is `nil` is a simple programming error. If this can occur, one should have a runtime check in place to guard against it.

Static analysis may be able to detect this type of bug ahead of time - but what if the variable `j` is accessible from another goroutine - how would the compiler know for sure that another goroutine may update it to a non-nil value right before the `range` loop is reached?

Answer (score -3):

Go has a zero value defined for each type when you initialize a variable with `var` keyword (this may change when using `:=`, ideally used when need copies of values or specific values). In the case of the pointer the zero value is nil (also maps, interfaces, channels, slices, and functions) in case of array of type int the zero value is 0.

So, to answer your question, Go is able to iterate because you have 33 valid spaces idependently of what value is inside of that position. You can check the diference between slices and arrays on the Golang documentation to have more insights on why is that.